# Is , "he says anything" and "he doesn't really think while saying something" means the same thing?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is **"He says anything"** and **"He doesn't really think while saying something?"** means similar.

Can anyone please help me correct me if I am wrong. If that's the case what is the proper way to sound idiomatic?

Answer (score 1):

*He speaks without thinking* is probably the most idiomatic.

*He says anything* could mean the same thing, but it could also be used in other contexts.

*Tell me if he says anything.*

*Show him the letter before he says anything.*